# URL automatically changes & it gives me the error of Page not found

Tags: django

"127.0.0.1:8000/adminpanel/edit_gallary/29"

So this is the main problem when I first edit it works properly. But when I want to edit the second time URL automatically changes & it changes this way.

**"127.0.0.1:8000/adminpanel/edit_gallary/edit_gallary/29"**

This is my views.py file:

```
 def edit_gallary(request,gallaryid):
        table = gallary.objects.get(id=gallaryid)
        gallary_form = gallaryform(instance=table)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form = gallaryform(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=table)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                table=gallary.objects.all()
                return render(request,"gallary1.html",{'table':table})
        context = {'gallary_form':gallary_form}
        return render(request,'edit_gallary.html',context)
```

This is my URLS.py file:

```
path('edit_gallary/<int:gallaryid>',views.edit_gallary,name="edit gallery"),
```

This is my edit_gallary.html file:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="app" id="app">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header-block header-block-collapse d-lg-none d-xl-none">
                    <button class="collapse-btn" id="sidebar-collapse-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="header-block header-block-nav">
                    <ul class="nav-profile">
                        <li class="profile dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="img"
                                    style="background-image: url('https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3959008?v=3&amp;s=40')">
                                </div>
                                <span class="name">Admin</span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu profile-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-power-off icon"></i> Logout </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
            <aside class="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-container">
                    <div class="sidebar-header">
                        <div class="brand">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <span class="l l1"></span>
                                <span class="l l2"></span>
                                <span class="l l3"></span>
                                <span class="l l4"></span>
                                <span class="l l5"></span>
                            </div> Compare school
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul class="sidebar-menu metismenu" id="sidebar-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="insert_school">
                                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Back</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <div class="sidebar-overlay" id="sidebar-overlay"></div>
            <div class="sidebar-mobile-menu-handle" id="sidebar-mobile-menu-handle"></div>
            <div class="mobile-menu-handle"></div>
            <article class="content responsive-tables-page">
                <div class="title-block">
                    <h1 class="title">Gallary</h1>
                    <p class="title-description"></p>
                </div>
                <section class="section">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">                     
                                        {{ gallary_form }}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-right mb-3">
                                                <input type="submit" value="register" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </form>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Comment: Kindly add template from which this edit functionality is linked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change `'edit_gallary/<int:gallaryid>'` to `'<int:gallaryid>/edit_gallary/'` in urls.py or just try adding a slash to the route end in your path

Comment: No man! It didn't work! Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: Show link to edit galllery (from template)